# Launch Daemon for NodeJS App Won't start on reboot

Tags: launchd, daemons

I've created the below launch daemon to run a nodejs program on startup ([tiddlywiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/#GettingStarted%20-%20Node.js) in this case):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Debug</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/tiddlywiki.stdout</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/tiddlywiki.stderr</string>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.activescott.tiddlywiki</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Wait</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
            <key>PATH</key>
            <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Volumes/minidata/Dropbox/tiddlywiki/node_modules/.bin/tiddlywiki</string>
            <string>/Volumes/minidata/Dropbox/tiddlywiki/wiki</string>
            <string>--listen</string>
            <string>credentials=creds.csv</string>
            <string>writers=scott</string>
            <string>readers=scott</string>
            <string>port=443</string>
            <string>host=0.0.0.0</string>
            <string>tls-key=key.pem</string>
            <string>tls-cert=server.crt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The file is named `com.activescott.tiddlywiki.plist` and it is in the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` folder.

If I load it with the command:

```
sudo launchctl load -Fw /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.activescott.tiddlywiki.plist
```

I start it with the below command it and wills tart and work fine - it just doesn't restart automatically when the comp reboots:

```
sudo launchctl start com.activescott.tiddlywiki
```

Note, it does take about ~20s to fully start (e.g. respond on a port and write to stdout).

I'm on Mac OS X, 10.13.6 w/ BuildVersion 17G13035

**Update**:

After a reboot I noticed that the output of `sudo launchctl list com.activescott.tiddlywiki` shows `LastExitStatus` as `19968`. This value will show 0 if I start it with launchctl. Below is the full output:

```
{
        "StandardOutPath" = "/tmp/tiddlywiki.stdout";
        "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
        "StandardErrorPath" = "/tmp/tiddlywiki.stderr";
        "Label" = "com.activescott.tiddlywiki";
        "TimeOut" = 30;
        "OnDemand" = true;
        "LastExitStatus" = 19968;
        "Program" = "/Volumes/minidata/Dropbox/tiddlywiki/node_modules/.bin/tiddlywiki";
        "ProgramArguments" = (
                "/Volumes/minidata/Dropbox/tiddlywiki/node_modules/.bin/tiddlywiki";
                "/Volumes/minidata/Dropbox/tiddlywiki/wiki";
                "--listen";
                "credentials=creds.csv";
                "writers=scott";
                "readers=scott";
                "port=443";
                "host=0.0.0.0";
                "tls-key=key.pem";
                "tls-cert=server.crt";
        );
};
```

Comment: Where do you specify the `Program` key? i.e. what/where is the program you're running?

Comment: Also have you tried to run this with a script rather than having multiple program arguments. There's also on mount setting, make sure you check if the path to volume exists. Also try with the following keep alive setting: 
`<key>KeepAlive</key> <dict> <key>SuccessfulExit</key> <true/> </dict>` This template seems to work so try with this as well: https://gist.github.com/lordlycastle/0efb8a10d2ccb7a90e4e5b1c9749ccf2

Comment: Please post the output of `grep -F com.activescott.tiddlywiki /var/log/system.log` after you reboot. (The last few lines of the output should be sufficient.)

Comment: Try removing the `OnDemand` and `RunAtLoad` keys entirely. The man page for launchd.plist advises against both. `KeepAlive` set to true should be enough to get the daemon rolling. Incidentally, I notice that you are loading the job with -Fw options. The -F option may cause launchctl to ignore the -w option (I'm not sure about that, but it's worth investigating), and if you unload with the -w option you'll automatically disable the job. I wouldn't use those options at all unless you have a reason to.

Comment: @user14492 My understanding is that you can use `Program` *or* `ProgramArguments`. Apple's recent examples use only `ProgramArguments` and it seems to work when I run it with launchctl load ...

Comment: @user14492 keepalive w/ succesfulexit as you have it didn't do the trick. :(

Comment: @Synoli `Jun 28 23:28:59 minicomp-ethernet com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.activescott.tiddlywiki): The Debug key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Jun 28 23:28:59 minicomp-ethernet com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.activescott.tiddlywiki[541]): inetd-compatible service with no sockets.`

Comment: @TedWrigley Removing `OnDemand` and `RunAtLoad` keys entirely didn't do it.

Comment: You could also get trial for [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) which is made to create deamons. (I'm not the dev, just use the app for these cases). And see what's different than one you created. I don't have to use terminal after enabling/creating a deamon.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your application can be run within the Terminal, making an AppleScript program (using *Script Editor*) containing the commands that you would run in the terminal and then exporting that program as a `Run-Only Application`, placing it in your `/Applications/` directory can create your program launcher.

[There is a helpful answer on using `do shell script` in AppleScript here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101518/how-to-create-an-apple-script-that-runs-a-terminal-command)

**AppleScript Example:** Running `hdiutil` to mount a sparseimage bundle as a Time Machine backup drive

```
do shell script "hdiutil attach /Volumes/NewVolumeD/TimeMachine.sparsebundle"
```

Then, navigating to **System Preferences > Users & Groups > (your account) > Login Items**, unlocking the settings menu and then using the `+` button on the bottom left to select your launcher application from `Applications`. That launcher will now run on login, check mark on `Hide` so that it doesn't throw unwanted messages.

Alternatively, you could make a `zsh` or `bash` script and tell AppleScript execute the shell script (given its absolute path) instead of specifying each command in AppleScript itself.

*EDIT: Instead of using Login Items, you can place the Application Bundle in `/Library/StartupItems` (though it is deprecated) if you want it to launch on startup instead of login.*

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Definitely not wanting to rely on applescript for starting a non-ui service though. Also I don't even know if applescript can even run on boot (but not on login)

Comment: It's all good! I don't really find a problem with AppleScript and non-UI programs because it still shows `stderr` output as a dialog, which for my purposes is good enough. But yeah, `launchd` would still be the way to go for anything more complex.